# Not counting Purusha Sukta, what castes are mentioned in Rig Veda?

Tags: rig-veda, caste-system

Brahmins are mentioned in connection with frogs and opinion is divided if they are being made fun of.

Book 7

HYMN CIII. Frogs.

> 1. THEY who lay quiet for a year, the Brahmans who fulfil their vows,
>      The Frogs have lifted up their voice, the voice Parjanya hath inspired.

But are the other castes mentioned anywhere besides the Purusha Sukta?

Comment: 'opinion is divided'... whose opinion are you referring to ? also, post the actual link of the text, along with original sanskrit verse. translations can be wrong, either by accident or intention.